# How to compile only modules with a specific tag with android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is it possible to avoid the compilation of modules marked with LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS=test when running ndk-build?

I cannot find any documentation on how to use LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS

Comment: You should probably check the android-building mailing list, as it's a more specialized place for such information.